# Запретить клиенту отправлять данные по ВебСокету

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

Планирую использовать FastAPI, в котором будет метод events - он будет посылать клиентам события в реальном времени (новое сообщение, кто то печатает, заявка, и другое)

Я бы не хотел чтобы клиенты лишний раз нагружали сеть, по своей глупости. Веб сокет - не должен ничего принимать от клиента, он и не будет, для этого - и не делаю логику принятия ответов от клиента, для этого есть другие методы. Но как запретить Клиентам отправлять данные по веб сокету, чтобы не было лишней нагрузки, если кто то начнет что то отправлять

Comment: Минимум нужно принимать кипэлайв пинпонг. Так логика приёма в сокете все равно будет реализована. Добавьте приёмник который будет пятисотить кодом 1007 или 1008 на любой запрос

Comment: @eri, а разве в этом случае, не будут данные загружены на Сервер / ВебСокет. Если более точнее, мне нельзя, чтобы клиент смог даже написать в ВебСокет, дабы не нагружать трафик (не о обработке текста-ответа идет речь, а более глубоком уровне отказа принимать данные)

Comment: Читай выше. Отказывать нельзя. В асинхронных движках можно рвать соединение до вычитывания тела. Принять только заголовки